# Files missing after *git svn clone*

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have a SVN repo and would like to use git from now on.

I tried to clone the repo with 2 approaches.

1. Normal SVN checkout
2. git svn clone

The first approach did just fine. Everything is fine and the project compiles. However, when I tried the second approach. I found that there were some files missing from the repo and therefore it wouldn't compile.

Any idea what's going here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your svn repository using [svn:external](http://www.simplisticcomplexity.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/)?

See [this article](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/02/moving-from-svn-to-git/) for more details on the migration process.