# git-svn clone file integrity

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I am responsible for moving some projects from a svn repository to git. I found out the workflow is fairly easy, its not more than a simple

```
git svn clone --stdlayout <svn-repo> <git-repo>
cd <git-repo>
java -jar ~/svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git --force
```

The svn-migration-scripts.jar can be found at [Atlassians Git Migration Guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview/), it converts the remote branches and tags to normal git branches and tags.

However, can I be sure that after performing these steps the local git repository really contains the same files as the svn repo? Especially after reading [Files Missing after svn clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187580/files-missing-after-git-svn-clone) I'd really like to be sure there are no differences in both repositorys. A colleague suggested writing a script that checks out every branch in git and svn, and then compares a hash sum of every file. I searched for a tool which does this, but I couldn't find one.

Is there a tool out there that compares the repositories against each other? Or is this functionality already built-in in git-svn? I'd be thankful for any suggestion or idea you have.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, one could check out [`lunatic-cat/xxhashdir`](https://github.com/lunatic-cat/xxhashdir), a standalone executable which does fast filesystem fingerprinting using **[`xxHash`](http://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/)**

> `xxHash` is an extremely fast non-cryptographic hash algorithm, working at speeds close to RAM limits.

If you have both the right SVN revision checked out and the Git repository, you can quickly generate a text file with a hash signature for each file, and you can compare/diff the two text files.